# Do I have to check READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE before checking if folder exists or listing its subfolders

Tags: android, android-permissions

I know that READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is needed to read files outside app storage, but how about folders. The official documentation (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) isn't very clear and other sources online are not helpful either. Do I have to check this permission before I check if some specific folder exists and what subfolders does it have?

Comment: Did you read this link? https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage

Comment: For checking if a folder exists you often do not need permissions. To list folders you need permissions on devices below Android 11. But... You can check this all so easily yourself.

Comment: Yes, I read that a few times. There is nothing about reading external folders, just about reading external files.

Comment: I only talked about exists and list. Not about read.

Comment: Well my main interest is to check if folder exists and what subfolders does it contain, but I don't mind more thorough answer about if READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is needed for additional info (origin date, change date, visibility). I don't want to avoid asking for the permission, I just want to make sure I ask just before it is really needed.

Comment: "You can check this all so easily yourself." Where could I read more about this?

Comment: No not read. Just try it out yourself was the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @blackapps suggested, checking if any folder exists works always without permission on API 23 device. Listing contents (subfolders) is more complicated:

- root and its subfolders (/): works without permissions
- user storage root and its subfolders (/storage/emulated/0, /sotrage/sdcard1, ...): needs permission

Still I'd like to know more universal answer.